# Suggestions dropdown overwrite datepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-datepicker

As in the picture I posted, you can see that the recommendations dropdown list on click is shown over the datepicker and it blocked the datepicker section. How could I solve this? Is it familliar to you?

Picture:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add **`<form autocomplete="off">`** in case the suggestions are not so important to you or that form.

It will prevent the appearing of suggestions in the first place. I'm not familliar with the suggestion, datepicker, some other script or add-on overwrite order.